# How do I convert Richtext images from a standard WPF RichTextBox into HTML using XSLT?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xslt, richtextbox

**How do I convert Richtext images from a standard WPF RichTextBox into HTML using XSLT?**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236483/c-sharp-flowdocument-to-html-conversion/6238403#6238403), I have made the following XSLT file. So far, it converts Bold, Italic, Underlined, font family, font size, and font color. Now I still need it to convert images in the Richtext to HTML.

Image alignment does not have to be considered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl x">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="x:Section[not(parent::x:Section)]">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:Section">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:Paragraph">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:Run">
    <xsl:variable name="style">
      <xsl:if test="@FontStyle='Italic'">
        <xsl:text>font-style:italic;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@FontWeight='Bold'">
        <xsl:text>font-weight:bold;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains(@TextDecorations, 'Underline')">
        <xsl:text>text-decoration:underline;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@FontSize != ''">
        <xsl:text>font-size:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@FontSize" />
        <xsl:text>pt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@FontFamily != ''">
        <xsl:text>font-family:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@FontFamily" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@Foreground != ''">
        <xsl:text>color:#</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(@Foreground, 4)"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <span>
      <xsl:if test="normalize-space($style) != ''">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($style)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Did you mean this `<FlowDocumentReader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<FlowDocument>
   <BlockUIContainer>
     <Image Source="Untitled.png"/>
    </BlockUIContainer>
</FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>` into `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="Untitled.png"/>
  </body>
</html>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this template - include it above the final </xsl:stylesheet>

```
  <xsl:template match="x:Image">
    <img src="@Source" />
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You may need to add more explanation.