# How do I email a FlowDocument and retain its formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I have a `FlowDocument` that I need to email out in WPF.  The issue is that formatting is now working correctly.  Figured it would simple enough doing it this way;

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("myemail@emailaddress.com", fromID);
var toAddress = new MailAddress(emailAddress, toID);
string boby = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd).Text;
string subject = "My email";
const string fromPassword = "mypassword"
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,

    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

While this works the problem is that it does not preserve the formatting of the `FlowDocument` `doc`

**edit:**
Based on the comments I followed the example here;
[C# FlowDocument to HTML conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236483/c-sharp-flowdocument-to-html-conversion)

The problem being that still doesn't preserve the formatting.  It would seem that his `FlowDocumentToXhtml` does not contain values for text alignment.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I believe you need to convert `FlowDocument` to HTML and send the email using HTML body

Comment: As stated above you'll want to convert the document to HTML (to preserve formatting). One approach to do so is described @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236483/c-sharp-flowdocument-to-html-conversion . Once you've converted it, make sure to send with `IsBodyHtml` set to `true`